# Sprite doesn't display in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite

I make simply aplication in LibGDX. I have got two textures (background and sprite). The background is diplayed ok but I don't see the sprite. I have tried many solutions but nothing works. I don't know what is going on. Thanks for help.

Here is my code:

```
public void create() {      
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("graphic/bg1.png"));
    bad = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("graphic/b.png"));
    layerOne = new TextureRegion(texture);
    spriteb = new Sprite(bad);
    rbg = new ParallaxBackground(new ParallaxLayer[]{
            new ParallaxLayer(layerOne, new Vector2(),new Vector2()),
            }, w, h,new Vector2());
}

public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    rbg.render();
    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    spriteb.setPosition(400, 200);
    spriteb.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: From comments on deleted answer: " I have constructor in ParallaxBackground: ParallaxBackground(ParallaxLayer[] layers,float width,float height,Vector2 speed) and in class ParallaxLayer ParallaxLayer(TextureRegion region,Vector2 parallaxRatio,Vector2 startPosition,Vector2 padding) so it looks ok, the rgb is ok, I can see spriteb = new Sprite(bad);"

Answer (score 2):

Your camera viewport is too small for the Sprite position

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);
...
spriteb.setPosition(400, 200);
```

The sprite is being rendered far outside of the viewport.

Try setting your camera like this:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(w, (h/w)*h);
```